# Como adicionar classe a todos li, menos ao que foi clicado

Tags: jquery

Eu quero adicionar uma classe `hidden` para todos `li`, mas não para o `li` que foi clicado. Como posso fazer isso usando jQuery?

```js
jQuery(".render-menu li").on('click', function() {
  alert();
  jQuery(".render-menu").not($(this)).parent().addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="render-menu">
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Foi erro de digitação, já fiz a correção.

Comment: É interessante notar que para aplicar a classe você não selecionou os elementos `<li>`, apenas a classe `.render-menu`, que é o `<ul>`; depois fez o *not* com o `this`, que não fará nada, pois o `this` será o `<li>` pressionado; depois pega o elemento pai, que será o elemento pai do `<ul>`, no exemplo será o `<body>` inteiro e, finalmente, você adiciona a classe `hidden`. Ao invés de ocultar o `<li>` você ocultou a página :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você já está usando o [`jQuery.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) que faz justamente o que você precisa, ele retorna um objeto jQuery removendo o elemento passado para ele do set.

```js
var $items = $(".render-menu li");

$items.on('click', function() {
  $items.not(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="render-menu">
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito bom jovem! Vou parar de responder questões de jQuery :D

Comment: Não pára não! hahahaha
Tem que movimentar isso aqui.

Comment: As vezes eu penso em parar para dar uma estudada aprofundada de jQuery, pq tudo que sei eu aprendi no tapa mesmo. Só que depois eu penso, melhor estudar Vanila JS de uma vez... Mas acaba que eu não para pra estudar é nada haha. Mas vejo que tenho que aprender melhor isso antes de responder "de qualquer jeito" pq vejo que as vezes posso inibir pessoas que deixam de dar uma resposta melhor que a minha só pq já tem uma resposta para a pergunta, mesmo não sendo "a melhor resposta"...

Comment: Sabendo Vanilla JS você já fica bem.. Na minha opinião a época do jQuery está passando, vale mais a pena estudar React ou Vue.

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode resolver usando os métodos `.hide()` e `.show()` dessa forma:

```js
jQuery(".render-menu li").on('click', function() {
  $(".render-menu li").hide();
  $(this).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="render-menu">
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ou só `$(".render-menu li").not(this).hide()`, para não esconder e exibir novamente :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse comentário completou o que uma voz estava dizendo na minha cabeça que "da pra fazer com uma linha só"... Valeu a dica!

Answer (score 3):

Existe ainda o método `siblings` do jQuery que retorna os elementos irmãos, isto é, elementos que estão no mesmo nível do DOM que o elemento em questão. Opcionalmente é possível definir um seletor como parâmetro, `siblings('li')`.

```js
$(".render-menu li").on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="render-menu">
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito bom jovem! Infelizmente acho que o jQuery vai morrer antes de eu aprender como ele funciona direito...